# Animated three,js texture not working correctly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I made a simple animation today. It's supposed to show days and nights going by. It works correctly in Chrome, but in Firefox, the texture animation gets stuck sometimes.

[Click to see](http://codepen.io/vahidseo/pen/FiCJe)

For the animated texture, I'm using a 2d Canvas:

```
mixedTexture = document.createElement ( 'canvas' );
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

A canvas can be created, but it must be added to the DOM as well. Try something like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );

canvas.id = 'canvasID';

document.body.appendChild( canvas ); 
document.getElementById( 'canvasContainer' ).appendChild( canvasID );
```

Once, the canvas is appended to the DOM, you can start your animation.

Comment: That's not what my question is about.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misread. I just tested it on FF 30.0 and see no issues.

Comment: The dark side of the earth lags sometimes. Visit it on Chrome to see the difference.